# How do I mark green pixels as 1 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to load an image into Matlab, and mark pixels in green as 1, and rest as 0, and display the final image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This depends a bit on the image, and the criteria for determining when a pixel is green. Must the pixel have only green, but no blue or red? If so, here's one way.

Start by loading the image and separating the colors:

```
image = imread('your_image.jpg');
red = image(:,:,1);
green = image(:,:,2);
blue = image(:,:,3);
```

Then, find pixels that have green but not red or blue:

```
only_green = green & ~(red | blue)
```

If you have a different definition of a green pixel, then you can alter this second step accordingly.

To display the resulting matrix as an image, use `imshow`.

Answer (score 1):

For making things more interesting, I suggest the following solution:

1. Convert input image from RGB to HSV.
2. Mark the green pixels in HSV color space (in HSV color space you can select other colors like Yellow (not only the prime colors: Red, Green, Blue)).

For emphasizing the green, I set other colors to gray-scale:

Here is my code:

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
HSV = rgb2hsv(RGB); %Convert RGB to HSV.

figure;imshow(RGB);title('Original');

%Convert from range [0, 1] to [0, 255] (kind of more intuitive...)
H = HSV(:, :, 1)*255;
S = HSV(:, :, 2)*255;
V = HSV(:, :, 3)*255;

%Initialize to zeros.    
Green = zeros(size(H));

%Needed trial and error to find the correct range of green (after Google searching).  
Green(H >= 38 & H <=160 & S >= 50 & V >= 30) = 1; %Set green pixels to 1

figure;imshow(Green);title('Mark Green as 1');

%Play with it a little...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Gray = rgb2gray(RGB); %Convert to gray-scale

R = RGB(:, :, 1);
G = RGB(:, :, 2);
B = RGB(:, :, 3);

Green = logical(Green);

R(~Green) = Gray(~Green);
G(~Green) = Gray(~Green);
B(~Green) = Gray(~Green);

RGB = cat(3, R, G, B);

figure;imshow(RGB);title('Green and Gray');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Result:

Original image:
[image]

Mark Green as 1:
[image]

Green and Gray:
[image]